# Issue with grep merged with IF under linux

Tags: linux, shell

Hi I  am trying to use grep with if and if the value is found under the directory it should update the file name with "_1" else copy to other directory

```
cd /home/inbound/ftp
f3=822220222 #ordernumber which change every time for this instance we use this 

   if [ grep -lq $f3 ]; then
   f4=`find . -name *$f3*` #trying to get the existing file name if available 
   mv "$f4" "$f4_1"        #updating existing file with "_1"
else
   cp $file /home/outbound/ftp
```

Comment: `[` is not part of the `if` statements syntax; it's the name of a command. `if grep -lq "$f3"; then`, but you are still missing a required argument for `grep`.

Comment: if grep -lq $f3  -ge 1; then i tried this as well but seems to have still have issue

Comment: if  grep -lq "$f3" *; i just tried this but this fails in doing the job of mv

Comment: `grep` needs a pattern *and* a file in which to find that pattern. Is `f3` the pattern, or the file name?

Comment: i want  to grep using the order number and if any file is found under the directory rename it  existing name_1

Comment: Then it sounds like you need the `-r` option for `grep`.

Comment: Or a single `find` command: `find . -type f -exec grep -q "$f3" {} \; -exec mv {} {}_1 \;`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

grep command can be used to search a pattern in a file or an output. it can be connected to ls with a pipe to check this. However for your scenario the below would be an better alternative to find if the file is present

```
cd /home/inbound/ftp
f3=822220222 #ordernumber which change every time for this instance we use this 

   if [ -f "*$f3*" ]; then
   f4=`find . -name *$f3*` #trying to get the existing file name if available 
   mv "$f4" "$f4_1"        #updating existing file with "_1"
else
   cp $file /home/outbound/ftp
```

However this checks for your order number in the variable f3. However you already know the filename that you are going to copy. so you can use that instead of f3.

```
cd /home/inbound/ftp
filename=`basename $file` #file name of the File being FTPed

   if [ -f $filename ]; then
   mv "$filename" "$filename_1"        #updating existing file with "_1"
   fi   # closing this here will make sure the file gets copied all the time
   cp $file /home/outbound/ftp
```

Comment: Please try to clean up your answer to follow best practices. `if [ -f "$filename" ]`; `filename=$(basename "$file")`, `cp "$file" /home/outbound/ftp`, etc. (Also, `[ -f "*$f3*" ]` is checking for a file with `*`s in its name; surely that's not what is wanted).

Comment: ...and `f4=$(find ...anything...)` is inherently buggy; see discussion in [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). `find` separates its outputs with newlines by default, but filenames can contain newlines. Moreover, `for file in $f4` splits on not just newlines but spaces, and expands glob characters, so files with glob characters or spaces in their names get mishandled. And if there's more than one file with `f3` in its name, then `mv "$f4" "$f4_1"` will fail (it'll also fail because `f4_1` is a valid variable name, but an empty one).

Comment: ...so, it would need to be `"${f4}_1"` to suffix a `_1` onto the result of expanding `$f4`.

Comment: if [ -f "$f3" ]; then
   f4=`find . -name *$f3*`
   mv "$f4" "${f4}_1"
 else
   cp $file /home/outbound/ftp
 fi

Comment: I tried this even if the file is present in directory it does not go to mv block and always going to else block.

Comment: filename=`basename $file`   
if [ -f $filename ]; then
  f4=`find . -name *$f3*`
  #mv "$f4" "${f4}_1"
   mv "$filename" "${filename}_1"
else
   cp $file home/outbound/ftp

Comment: This works partially for the first time it worked and changed the name with {filename}_1 , but with the second run when same order number used and the file name available with  {filename_1} now it throws error instead of updating to {filename_1}_1

Comment: this is the error i receive                                                                                              find: paths must precede expression: filename_1
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory                                                                                could any help please i am new to scripting

Comment: mv "$filename" "$filename_1"
instead of this line try this
mv "$filename" "${filename}_$(date '+%s')"